# Angular Reactive forms novalidate not working

Tags: html, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

Angular Reactive Forms not disabling HTML5 default validations when added `novalidate`.

Please check this [plunker link.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qnMJJlUe9YyJ7WwSIDBk?p=preview)

I've added `novalidate` on form, but it still validates the text input on basis of pattern attribute. When added `novalidate` it should ignore the pattern validation.

I've added the pattern as I want to open numeric keypad on that text input.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what is the problem. BTW, if you are using angular v 4 ->, novalidate is automatically applied to form, you don't need to use it. And why not set `Validators.pattern` instead of having `pattern` in template. Utilize the reactive form ;)

Comment: To open the numeric keypad on iOS devices I need to set pattern as `[0-9]+` on text input fields. But I don't want this pattern to validate that input. So that I'm adding `novalidate`.

Comment: doesn't it work if you set `Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")` instead of `pattern` in template?

Comment: and as said, Angular automatically sets `novalidate` to forms if you are using v.4 ->

Comment: and what does *I don't want this pattern to validate that input*, if not, why are you setting a validation?

Comment: Yes, I'm using v4 ->. But I don't want to validate my input using that pattern. It is just used to open numeric keypad on the iOS device.

Comment: Aah now I am starting to understand, but you are misunderstanding what `novalidate` means. It doesn't remove the validation. But pre angular 4 you needed to set that if you wanted to avoid the `please fill out this field`, i.e https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/tutorials/constraintvalidation/ChromeForAndroid.png So `novalidate` is not the correct implementation here. But since I am not familiar with mobile development I cannot help you further, unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks for your help @AJT_82. But `novalidate` also removes the pattern validation. Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/5q6a1MUBKDb3caFeFHSU?p=preview

Comment: that is not angular and as I said... `novalidate` is automatically applied since angular 4. Now you need to specify it: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_no_validate_directive.ts#L16

Comment: Angular is different from HTML5, in Angular `novalidate` means removing the native validation, stopping these popups like `please select a field`.